# Aligning textfield vertically in the middle of its background

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to align the text field in the middle of that light gray background around it. As you can see in the screenshot it is a little bit off vertically. It seems to be sitting a little lower.
[image: textfield]

Here is minimized code for the text field:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Message: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let content: String
    let isUser: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textFieldContent = ""
    @State private var settingsShown = false
    @State private var toggleIsOn = false
    @State private var messages: [Message] = [] // now 'Message' type
    @State private var isTyping = false // to show animation

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VisualEffectView()
            
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(spacing: 10) {
                            ForEach(messages) { message in
                                if message.isUser {
                                    HStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(message.content) // <- change here
                                            .padding(7)
                                            .background(Color.blue)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .trailing) // Align the text to the right for user messages
                                    }
                                    .padding(.trailing, 10) // Padding on right side for user messages
                                } else {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(message.content) // <- and here
                                            .padding(7)
                                            .background(Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .leading) // Align the text to the left for AI messages
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    .padding(.leading, 10) // Padding on left side for AI messages
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                    
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .background(
                    Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1)
                )
                .overlay(
                    Button(action: {
                        settingsShown.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding()
                    }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
                )
                
                HStack {
                    TextField("Send a message", text: $textFieldContent)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        .focusable(false)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Send")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }
                .padding(1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        let view = NSVisualEffectView()
        view.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        view.state = .active
        view.material = .underWindowBackground
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        // No update code needed here for this example.
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it's the background around the textfield that affects the positioning or the textfield itself. I tried to play with the padding and the properties but did not achieve anything.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you posted does not produce the image you posted. I think you missed some code.

Comment: Hey @Yrb I updated the code to my best ability to reproduce what is in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra padding you're seeing is the spacing between the elements of the VStack. If you set the `spacing` of the top-level VStack to 0, I believe you'll get the layout you mean:

```
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
```

If you add borders (`.border(.green)`) to the elements of the VStack, you can see better where they are and the spacing between them.

Comment: So I tried your method, and it changes the layout of the actual messages in the final code. I also tested it with the green border. Here is a screenshot, in the blue is what I need. The `Send message` field to be centered in the lighter gray area. https://ibb.co/qYNWSDH

Comment: You have likely added your spacing (and border) to the wrong VStack. Move up the hierarchy to the top-level VStack.